# Android AlertDialog always exits when I click on OK Button

Tags: android

Is there some way to do validation upon clicking ok. Im not dismissing it but it closes when I click Ok. I have written a custom AlertDialog that uses some edit texts. Problem is I can't validate anything. If validation fails I want to change message and tell user but instead it just closes.  I'm using AlertBuilder

```
        builder.setPositiveButton(DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  // I don't dismiss here.
                }

           }
```

Comment: can u show some code....

Comment: fallow above comments please....

Comment: post your answers.  There are other things to write beside -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the onClickListener. The trick is to get the button after create  and showing the dialog.

```
//  Create you dialog here and show it
...
dialog.show();

Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View onClick) {
        //  Valid checking
        ...

        if (valid) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            //  Not valid
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: perhaps after show as well and not just after builder.create()?

Comment: seems to work now that I placed the above code after dialog.show()

Answer (score -1):

if you write nothing inside onClick method definately it will dismiss whether you want or not, then why you asking this question as  you have not write anything inside that method. as It is alertdialog it will get closed and if you dont want it close then use **setNeutralButton** instead of **setPositiveButton**. It wont close if you use neutral button

Comment: setNeutralButton also closes automatically

Comment: Definitely not enough to just use neutral.

Comment: then dont use Alert Dialog, instead make your own custom dialog

Comment: There can be reasons to use AlertDialog ... Rather than rolling your own.

Comment: thats what i am saying, there can be reasons too, that they let u make custom dialogs, when you do not just want to prompt to user, when you want a user to input somethings and inside that manipulate the input, but you want to display output on same dialog then its no more an alert dialog, its simply a dialog, alert dialogs are to alert the users for something. Like we can make a sign in dialog , it should be in custom dialog not in alert dialog and It provides you everything custom that you take a view same as custom list view.